# Variable does not exist: Decimal

Tags: apex, error, decimal

I have the following code:

```
fieldList = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped('['+ JSONValueRights +']');

for(Object fld : fieldList){    
    Map<String,Object> data = (Map<String,Object>)fld;
    RightsTrackerListValue.Add(new Rights_Tracker__c(Category__c = (String)data.get('category'), Product__c = (String)data.get('product'), Details__c = (String)data.get('details'), Agreement__c = Decimal.valueOf(data.get('agreement'))));
}
```

I'm trying to get the agreement to be converted to a decimal.

Looking at the following [page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm) I can see that decimal has a method called .valueOf where I can pass a string and get it converted to decimal.

However I get the error 'decimal does not exist'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should convert the `Object` to `String` first. And then `String` to `Decimal`:

```
Object o = '2.52';
String s = String.valueOf(o);
Decimal d = Decimal.valueOf(s);
```

In the [Decimal docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm): the `valueOf(...)` method can take as parameter:

- Double
- String
- Long

but not the `Object`!

So in your code use:

```
Decimal.valueOf(String.valueOf(data.get('agreement')))
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey. I should of noticed that. Much appreciated. Will mark as answer asap.